# C++ : "reset" std::next_permutation()

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Is there a way to "reset" `std::next_permutation()`? Let's say I want to go over the permutations of the vector several times. The only thing I was able to find is to go through `next_permutation` and `prev_permutation` alternatively.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"resetting" would be sorting the sequence, e.g. using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Note that you *have* to start off with a sorted sequence if you want to enumerate all permutations using `next_permutation`.

Also, [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) will return `false` once the lexicographically smallest permutation is reached again.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you